# Iterate for loop by dynamic value in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angularJS.

I want to iterate for loop.

Here is my try,

```
totalDays = 4;
<tr ng-repeat="key in totalDays">
    ...
</tr>
```

But i can't able to loop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your controller ???

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-repeat.asp

Comment: Thanks @Edison. But in [this](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-repeat.asp) example loop through array. But i have only single integer value.

Comment: @JaydeepMor can you show the value of` totalDays`

Comment: kindly post your js code in your controller

Comment: Yes @Edison check my edited answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the number to a function and generate an array as follows,

```
 $scope.getDays = function(num) {
    return new Array(num);   
 }
```

**DEMO**

```js
 var app = angular.module('myapp',[]);
 app.controller('personController',function($scope){
  $scope.totalDays = 4;
  $scope.getDays = function(num) {
    return new Array(num);   
 }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app = "myapp" ng-controller = "personController">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="i in getDays(totalDays) track by $index"><span>{{$index+1}}</span></li>
</ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Working well. Thank you very much !. @Sajeetharan